# Решая лабиринт в Java?

Tags: java

Поскольку в программе должны присутствовать общие классы `Queue`, `Stack` и `Coordinate`, необходимо создать *4 объекта*:

- Один объект класса `Stack <Coordinate>`, называемый `«path»`, и объект
  класса Stack > под названием `«возможности»`, оба из
  которых могут хранить 40 координат (5 x 8 - 5 строк и 8 столбцов);
- Один объект класса `Queue <Coordinate>`, называемый `«queue»`, который
  хранит 3 координаты и ставит в очередь пустые пробелы или символ `«S»`
  вокруг текущей позиции, найденной при поиске по всем 4 направлениям.
  (В первом поиске, например, очередь будет: `[(1,1),,] As 1,1` - это
  первое свободное место, найденное из начальной позиции, которое затем
  добавляется в очередь).
- Один объект класса `Coordinate`, называемый `«current»`, который
  представляет текущую позицию.

5 представляет количество строк. 8 - количество столбцов. Символ `#` представляет собой стену, непроходимую местность. Символ `E` является стартовой позицией, символ `S` - это выход, а пустые пробелы (`char ''`) представляют собой пробелы. Таким образом, программа сначала передает лабиринт текстового файла в матрицу с указанным числом строк и столбцов на ней `(5 и 8)`, а затем находит символ `E`, который является стартовой позицией и создает "*текущую*" Объект, сохраняя на нем свою координату (`(1,0)` в случае).

Оттуда он ищет все 4 направления вокруг текущей позиции по часовой стрелке (вверх, вправо, вниз и влево в этом порядке) и сохраняет координаты пустых пространств (или `char 'S'`), найденных в объекте `"queue"` И удаляет первую координату из «*очереди*», сохраняя эту координату на «*текущем*» объекте, который представляет текущую позицию. Затем, на матрице, помещает символ `*` в позицию, представленную «*текущим*» объектом (координатой), указывая, что был сделан шаг. Затем складывает объект «*текущий*» в объект «*путь*» и складывает объект «*очередь*» на объект «*возможности*».
Затем повторяет эти шаги, пока не найдет выход (символ `S`), печать матрицы и закрытие программы.

В конце, поскольку каждая позиция отмечена символом `*`, матрица должна выглядеть так:
(Текстовый файл не изменяется).

```
   5
   8
   ########
   E***   #
   ###*####
   ###*####
   ###S####
```

До сих пор я создавал классы:

***Queue***:

```
public class Fila <T> {
    private Object[objfila] = null;
    private int quantidade,posinicial,posfinal;
    public void inserir(Object x) throws Exception
    {
        if(quantidade==objfila.length)
            throw new Exception("Queue is full");
        x=objfila(posfinal);
        quantidade++;
        posfinal++;
    }
    public void remover() throws Exception
    {
        if(quantidade==0){
            throw new Exception("there are no elements on the queue");
        }
        quantidade--;
        posinicial++;
    }
    public Fila(int capacidade)
    {
        this.posinicial=0;
        this.posfinal=0;
        Object objfila=new Object();
    }
}
```

***Stack***:

```
public class Pilha <T> {
    private Object[] objpilha = null;
    private int topo;
    public void inserir(T x) throws Exception
    {
        if(topo==objpilha.length-1){
            throw new Exception("the stack is full.");
        }
        topo++;
        objpilha[topo]=x;
    }
    public void remover() throws Exception
    {
        if(topo==-1){
            throw new Exception("there are no elements to be removed.");
        }
        topo--;
    }
    public Pilha(int capacidade){
        objpilha=new Object[capacidade];
        topo=-1;
    }
}
```

> And Coordinate: (I think there should be an array of x and y that
>   stores coordinates)

```
public class Coordenadas <T>{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```

У меня возникают проблемы с созданием этих объектов и вставкой их в другие объекты, например, при сохранении найденных координат в «*очереди*» и при укладке «*текущего*» объекта в объект «*путь*». Как правильно сделать эту программу?

Извините за длинный вопрос.

Comment: Извините за нескромный вопрос - и откуда такая задача?

Comment: Похоже на курсовую. метод main выложи и какая ошибка возникает.